# Oracle procedure passes different result when calling in oracle form and the same in sql developer

Tags: plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I tried calling a procedure with 3 input parameters and 3 out parameters in both Oracle forms .pll file as well as in sql developer. Even I expected the same output parameter values for both cases, it gives different results. I confirmed printing a message on .pll and they are exactly same as I used in sql developer. Can anybody explain what the cause for such discrepancy is. Thanks.

**In .pll**

```
p_enquiry_date       pp_acc.end_date%type := to_date((nvl(name_in('PPUN.DSP_RUN_END_DATE'),
                                                         to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY'))),'DD-MON-YYYY');

message('enq: '||p_enquiry_date);pause;
```

It prints 'enq: 11-JAN-23'

**In Sql Developer,**

```
p_enquiry_date       pp_acc.end_date%type := to_date('11-JAN-2023','DD-MON-YYYY');
```

Comment: The most common reason for this is date format issues. Do all of your query use explicit date formats? Although the database has a default date format, the session often overrides it, and different tools user different default date formats. For example, if the query has an expression like `the_date = '01/02/2000'`, the query may work differently depending on if the session is set to `MM/DD/YYYY` or `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Comment: @JonHeller, Thanks for the comment. I tried with different date format, but it still gives the same result. I edited the question for your easy reference.

Comment: Use extended SQL trace to see what the RDBMS is doing. Then you'll know and won't have to guess.

Comment: @JeffHolt, Thanks for the comment. I tried executing 'ALTER SESSION SET EVENTS '10046 TRACE NAME CONTEXT FOREVER, LEVEL 12'; However, it only shows the output for the queries on sql developer.

Comment: You haven't said what output parameters you actually get from the two calls, or what the code is doing to produce those, or their data types. "Different result" doesn't tell us much. Your `message` call is implicitly converting a date to a string using your session NLS settings, so maybe you are still just doing that somewhere, even if you fixed the string-to-date conversions.

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view, everything is OK. It is not about date value itself, but the way it is *presented* to you.

Both Forms and SQL Developer **show** these date values using format mask valid at that moment.

In SQL*Plus (easier to demonstrate), we set it by

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
----------
17.10.2023
```

If I change my mind, I can

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-MON-yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-----------
17-OCT-2023
```

Or, to display time component as well:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
10/17/2023 07:02:13

SQL>
```

`sysdate` is the same in all cases, it is just about the way you **see** it.

The same goes with Forms; its date format is set to `dd-MON-yy` or `dd-MON-rr` so you see it as `11-OCT-23`, but it is as valid as any other format.

If you have to do some *date arithmetic* with that variable, no problem - you can, and all values will be OK as you're dealing with `date` datatype.

You *could* modify the way you see that value - the simplest way is to apply `to_char` with desired format mask, e.g.

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, 'yyyy-MON-dd') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYY
--------------------
2023-OCT-17
```

but this is now a **string** (and so is e.g. 'ABC' or 'Littlefoot' etc.) so - for date arithmetic operations - you'd now have to either convert it back to date (using `to_date`, again with appropriate format mask that matches that string) or - worse - rely on Oracle's implicit datatype conversion capabilities, and that's simple *wrong*. Imagine you see this value: `02/04/08`. What is it?

- 2nd of April 2008
- 4th of August 2002
- 8th of February 2004

Could be *any* of these values - that's why format model matters.

Once again: as long as you work with `date` datatype, you're fine. Don't go to the dark side and work with characters (representing date values).

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, Thanks for the comment. But in my code, I always convert the date variables to date type. So, how the result is varied between forms and Sql Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the setup:

```sql
CREATE TABLE pp_acc(end_date DATE);

CREATE PROCEDURE message(v_msg VARCHAR2)
  IS BEGIN DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_msg); END;
/

CREATE PROCEDURE pause
  IS BEGIN NULL; END;
/

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS';
```

Then using:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_enquiry_date pp_acc.end_date%type;

  FUNCTION name_in(v_col VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE
    IS BEGIN RETURN SYSDATE; END;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

  p_enquiry_date  := to_date(
                       (
                         nvl(
                           name_in('PPUN.DSP_RUN_END_DATE'),
                           to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                         )
                       ),
                       'DD-MON-YYYY'
                     );
  message('enq: '||p_enquiry_date);
  pause;
END;
/
```

Fails with the exception:

> ```
> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
> ORA-06512: at line 9
> ```

Because my `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is set to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` and the `NAME_IN` function will perform an implicit type conversion from date-to-string and output the first parameter in the format `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` when `TO_DATE` expects the format `DD-MON-YYYY` and you are mixing implicit and explicit formatting of dates (i.e. `NAME_IN` converts date-to-string implicitly providing the format and then you convert back to a date using an explicit format model).

If we change to explicitly use the correct format:

```
DECLARE
  p_enquiry_date pp_acc.end_date%type;

  FUNCTION name_in(v_col VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
    IS BEGIN RETURN TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY'); END;
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

  p_enquiry_date  := to_date(
                       (
                         nvl(
                           name_in('PPUN.DSP_RUN_END_DATE'),
                           to_char(sysdate, 'DD-MON-YYYY')
                         )
                       ),
                       'DD-MON-YYYY'
                     );
  message('enq: '||p_enquiry_date);
  pause;
END;
/
```

Then the output is:

> ```
> enq: 2023-10-17 00:00:00
> ```

The statement work but the output is probably not in the format you are expecting. This is because `'enq: '||p_enquiry_date` is performing an implicit date-to-string conversion and is effectively evaluated as:

```sql
'enq' || TO_CHAR(
  p_enquiry_date,
  (SELECT value FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT')
)
```

You could change the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter to `DD-MON-YYYY` but **don't** (any user can change their NLS session parameters at any time so you should not rely on implicit casts).

Instead, use consistent data-types throughout:

If `NAME_IN` is a built-in Oracle forms function that returns a `VARCHAR2` data type then either:

1. Use `VARCHAR2` throughout. This is an exceptional case where a built-in function breaks the rule about not using implicit type-conversions so we can apply some common sense and, in this case, it is easier to rely on implicit date formatting throughout rather than mixing implicit and explicit date formats (general rules are good, but sometimes they get broken and you need to know which bits of them to uphold, in this case its "not mixing implicit and explicit date formats" rather than the more general "don't use implicit type conversions"):

   ```sql
   DECLARE
     p_enquiry_date VARCHAR2(50);

     FUNCTION name_in(v_col VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
       IS BEGIN RETURN SYSDATE; END;
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

     p_enquiry_date  := nvl(name_in('PPUN.DSP_RUN_END_DATE'), to_char(sysdate));
     message('enq: '||p_enquiry_date);
     pause;
   END;
   /
   ```

   Which outputs formatted as the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` (so if yours is set to `DD-MON-YYYY` then it will output in that format):

   > ```
   > enq: 2023-10-17 09:15:34
   > ```

   or else;
2. Use `DATE`s and convert `NAME_IN` back to a date and apply the appropriate formatting when passing to `message`:

   ```sql
   DECLARE
     p_enquiry_date pp_acc.end_date%type;

     FUNCTION name_in(v_col VARCHAR2) RETURN VARCHAR2
       IS BEGIN RETURN SYSDATE; END;
   BEGIN
     DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();

     p_enquiry_date  := nvl(TO_DATE(name_in('PPUN.DSP_RUN_END_DATE')), sysdate);
     message('enq: '||TO_CHAR(p_enquiry_date, 'DD-MON-YYYY'));
     pause;
   END;
   /
   ```

   Which outputs:

   > ```
   > enq: 17-OCT-2023
   > ```

   Alternatively, but not recommended:
3. Run:

   ```sql
   ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-YYYY';
   ```

   Before running your PL/SQL block.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/TVHpIkZN)